# Laurent series for $\frac{1}{(z-1)^2(z+2)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find Laurent expansions for $$\frac{1}{(z-1)^2(z+2)}$$

in $A_1 = D(0,1)$, $A_2 = {z : 1 < |z| < 2}$, $A_3 = {{z : \sqrt{2} < |z-i| < \sqrt{5}}}$

I've split it into partial fractions and am trying to apply Taylor's expansion to the square term and convergent sum of geometric to the other two. I'm confused because I'm not sure how you're meant to know the expansion point (like $z$ or $z-1$ etc). Please can someone tell me how to do the $A_2$ scenario? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

For $\dfrac 1{(z-1)^2}$, note that it equals $-(\dfrac 1{z-1})'$.

So since (geometric series) $\dfrac 1{z-1}=\dfrac 1z\dfrac 1{1-\frac 1z}=\sum_{n\ge0}z^{-n}$, differentiate term by term.

Get $\dfrac 1{(z-1)^2}=-\sum_{n\ge0}-nz^{-(n+1)}$, on $\lvert z\rvert \gt1$.  This is about $z_0=0$.

Since $\dfrac 1{z+2}=\dfrac 12\dfrac 1{1-(-\frac z2)}=\dfrac 12\sum_{n\ge0}(-\dfrac z2)^n$ on $\lvert z\rvert \lt2$, now you just combine.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I thought too (though I didn't think to do the squared one like that, I was going to use Taylor series. I'm very new to Laurent series, so could I ask a couple of follow up questions?

Comment: 1) Might be stupid but how do you know that they want the series in terms of z, rather than z-1 or z-2?

Comment: 2) The boundaries for this questions seem to be quite "random". Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: When they ask for one on $1\lt\lvert z\rvert \lt2$, that suggests around zero.   The last region suggests around $i$.  See why?